# Separating persistence model and domain model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, n-tier-architecture

Finally starting to get the hang of Domain Driven Design, and in my mind it makes sense to separate the persistance model (PM) from the domain model (DM).

- DM contains factory functions
- DM contains events triggered in factory functions
- DM is immutable(only created through factory)

Since mapping from PM to DM should be done in the repository and the DM should be *immutable* and not know about the PM, should I just create a factory function that takes all the parameters but now call the event?

The service layer converts DTO to DM by using the factory functions, then maps back to DTO when task if finished.

Or go with the easy way and create a factory function inside the DM that takes PM as a parameter, and the other way around?

**My solution would be**: Trade some purity and clearness from DDD, to make the design a more efficient and decrease the complexity.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because it's too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: If Stack Overflow can't help, who can...

Comment: I don't know, but it's just the way it is, questions have to meet certain standards, see [ask].

Comment: Well, thank you for your effort. Think i will give up some purity and as said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service layer knows about both all layers involved: DTO, DM, PM, and repository, so it is the best place to do all kinds of conversions.

In a typical flow, assuming you are acting on an API call, you would:

- Construct a DTO from request parameters
- Construct a Domain Model by transferring the DTO to a factory method in the Domain Model
- Pass the new Domain Model to the repository for persistence (DM-to-PM and PM-to-DM methods are within the repository)
- Convert the persisted Domain Model to a DTO to ship back to outer layers

Comment: Thank you sir, i thought about the same sequence, just wanted some opinions.

Comment: Would have to place the domain models, persistance and repositories in the same library though, because of C#.

Comment: But how would i construct the DM from a PM, when the DM is immutable? Should i make a factory function inside the DM that accepts PM as argument and dosen't trigger any events? Whats your take on this?

Comment: PM to DM conversion is the responsibility of the repository. The repository could contain methods like `to_entity` and `from_entity` that help with these conversions.

Comment: Also, your point brings out the need to have a separate factory method, apart from the constructor, to initialize new domain objects. Constructors should only be used for reconstituting objects, usually from data stores, and should not contain business validations. Factory methods are the place to handle these invariants and construct valid objects.

Comment: Thank you sir! Ended up going for the constructor approach.